# Double and Triple Tonguing Syllables?

Tags: brass, woodwinds, articulation, tonguing

Brass and Woodwind players use specific syllables like ta-ka-ta for triple tonguing...

I would like to know:

- What are the most common used syllables for double and triple tonguing?
- Are they different for Woodwinds and Brass instruments?
- Do they use different syllables depending on the tempo of the piece, or do they work equally with any tempo?
- ...or are there even "common" syllables that "everyone" uses?

Comment: a) Ithink takata is the most commonI use for triplets  
I use tkt, tgd or  tgr depending of the situation  (Bariton and Euphonium)

Comment: Even Bach used it, in his famous   Takata and Fugue  (sorrynotsorry)

Answer (score 4):

I can only speak for the brass side of things, but the standard double-tonguing syllables are either "ta-ka" or some variant thereof. Variants include "ta-ga" or "da-ga," depending on the musical context. For instance, sometimes the "ka" syllable is too accented, so players conceptualize "ga" instead. Similarly, the "ta" may be much stronger than the "ka/ga," leading some players to conceptualize this as "da."

As for triple tonguing, I've always used "ta-ka-ta" (with the same variant caveats as above), but some players swear by "ta-ta-ka."

In my experience, the only reason tempo would change this is if the tempo is so slow that I don't even need to double/triple tongue. In such cases, I just stick with single tonguing.